# How to avoid moving below widgets when Visibility widget is toggled in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have this dialog that is using the `Visibility` widget inside one of the `Step`s:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return AlertDialog(
              insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              content: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
                return SizedBox(
                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                    height: constraints.maxHeight,
                    child: Form(
                      key: widget.formKey,
                      child: Stepper(
                        elevation: 0,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        type: StepperType.horizontal,
                        currentStep: _currentStep,
                        controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails controls) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                if (_currentStep != 0)
                                  ElevatedButton(
                                    style: const ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.grey)),
                                    onPressed: controls.onStepCancel,
                                    child: const Text(
                                      'BACK',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                const Spacer(),
                                if (_currentStep < 2)
                                  ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: controls.onStepContinue,
                                    child: const Text('NEXT'),
                                  ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        steps: [
                          Step(...),
                          Step(
                              state:
                              _currentStep > 1 ? StepState.complete : StepState.disabled,
                              isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
                              title: const Text(''),
                              // title: const Text('Schedule'),
                              content: Container(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child:
                                          TextFormField(
                                            enabled: false,
                                            onSaved: (value) => setState (() => widget.task.scheduleDate = _selectedDate.value),
                                            controller: _dateController,
                                            validator: (value) => value!.isEmpty ? "Date Schedule" : null, // NEEDED?
                                            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Date Schedule"),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        ElevatedButton(
                                          onPressed: () => setState (() => _restorableDatePickerRouteFuture.present()),
                                          child: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child:
                                          TextFormField(
                                            enabled: false,
                                            onSaved: (value) => setState (() => widget.task.scheduleTime = _selectedTime.value),
                                            controller: _timeController,
                                            validator: (value) => value!.isEmpty ? "Time Schedule" : null, // NEEDED?
                                            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Time Schedule"),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        ElevatedButton(
                                          onPressed: () => setState (() => _restorableTimePickerRouteFuture.present()),
                                          child: const Icon(Icons.access_time_outlined),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        const Expanded(
                                          child:
                                          Text('Repeat'),
                                        ),
                                        Switch(
                                            value: _isShowingRepeat,
                                            onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _isShowingRepeat = value)
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Visibility(
                                        visible: _isShowingRepeat,
                                        child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              WeekdaySelector(
                                                onChanged: (int day) {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    final index = day % 7;
                                                    _weekdaySelection[index] = !_weekdaySelection[index];
                                                  });
                                                },
                                                values: _weekdaySelection
                                                )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                ]),
                              )),
                          Step(...)
                        ],
                        onStepContinue: () {
                          if (_currentStep < 2) {
                            setState(() {
                              _currentStep += 1;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        onStepCancel: () {
                          if (_currentStep == 0) {
                            return;
                          }
                          setState(() {
                            _currentStep -= 1;
                          });
                        },
                        onStepTapped: (int index) {
                          setState(() {
                            _currentStep = index;
                          });
                        },
                      )),
                    );
              }),
              title: const Text('Task'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(null);
                  },
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: const Text('DONE'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (widget.formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(widget.task);
                      _handleSubmit(widget.task);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
      });
  }
```

My problem with that is when the "Repeat" toggle is switched and the `Visibility` switches accordingly too, the underneath widgets like buttons BACK and DONE move up and down. Is it possible to avoid this "bouncing effect"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this property to true

```
maintainSize, maintainState, maintainAnimation
```